# CMake and header search paths

Tags: cmake

I'm porting a project to CMake, and struggling to find how to set header search paths (previously set with compiler flags e.g. `-I "../../Source"`).

I currently have:

```
target_include_directories (jni-bridge PRIVATE
    "../../Analysis"
    "../../Source"
)
```

But this does not work. How should I set the paths, and what location are they relative to?

Comment: Why don't you add those directories in search path in higher level CMakeLists.txt? If those are not part of the current CMake project, then it would be better to add those directories with some CMake variable to make the project portable.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, CMake uses **absolute** paths as include directories. If relative path is used with [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/target_include_directories.html), then it is interpreted relative to the *current source directory* (`${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`).

---

The above is true when *generator expressions* are not used.

Generator expression `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:..>` may (and strongly recommended to) use relative path which is interpreted relative to the install prefix.

Generator expression `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:...>` should use absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes here for a simple and direct code example, referring to the example at https://cmake.org/examples/, append the following to the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
target_include_directories( helloDemo
  path/to/header1.h
  path/to/header2.h
)
```